# Flutter : Sort a list alphabetically taking "accented characters" into account

Tags: list, flutter, sorting

I have created a list sorting function which sorts a list of words & their French translations. The user can get a sorted list in English and in French. No problem in English, but in French, words starting with accented characters like 'é' find themselves at the end of the list instead of right after "e". For example : "érable" (maple) is the last word of one of my lists.
I tried by using "toUpperCase()" function hoping it would solve it, but it doesn't work.

Here's the code :

```
void _sortBufferCarnetList(_myList) {
    if (_selectedLanguage == Language.english) {
      _myList.sort((a, b) => wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[a].idDico]
          .main
          .toUpperCase()
          .compareTo(
              wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[b].idDico].main.toUpperCase()));
    } else if (_selectedLanguage == Language.french) {
      _myList.sort((a, b) => wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[a].idDico]
          .mainFr
          .toUpperCase()
          .compareTo(
              wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[b].idDico].mainFr.toUpperCase()));
    }
  }
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: See this answer to replace accented characters in strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30845046/11548872

Comment: But I don't really need to replace the characters... It seems it's not the same issue.

Comment: replace them and then you can sort

Comment: and then I need to replace them again with the accented characters ? How ?

Comment: create a removeAccents() function that returns the new String without accents. It will not change your initial list.


_myList.sort((a, b) => wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[a].idDico]
          .main
          .toUpperCase().removeAccents()
          .compareTo(
              wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[b].idDico].main.toUpperCase().removeAccents()));

Comment: I understant what you mean. But How do you create a function that you can add inside the code like ".removeAccents()" ?

Comment: See my answer with code

Comment: What do you think of the answer I wrote ?

Comment: If it covers all your need, it seems good and readable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236144/discussion-between-sylvainjack-and-luca-oropallo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer to the problem I found using the help of Luca Oropallo.

Here's the code :

```
String removeAccents(String str) {
    var withDia =
        'ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëðÇçÐÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÑñŠšŸÿýŽž';
    var withoutDia =
        'AAAAAAaaaaaaOOOOOOOooooooEEEEeeeeeCcDIIIIiiiiUUUUuuuuNnSsYyyZz';

    for (int i = 0; i < withDia.length; i++) {
      str = str.replaceAll(withDia[i], withoutDia[i]);
    }

    return str;
  }

  void _sortBufferCarnetList(_myList) {
    if (_selectedLanguage == Language.english) {
      _myList.sort((a, b) => wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[a].idDico]
          .main
          .toUpperCase()
          .compareTo(
              wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[b].idDico].main.toUpperCase()));
    } else if (_selectedLanguage == Language.french) {
      _myList.sort((a, b) => removeAccents(
              wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[a].idDico].mainFr.toUpperCase())
          .compareTo(removeAccents(
              wordBank[_bufferCarnetWordBank[b].idDico].mainFr.toUpperCase())));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  final data = ["érable", "Eeee", "égalité", "AaaAa", "zzz"];
  
  data.sort((a, b) => removeDiacritics(a.toUpperCase()).compareTo(removeDiacritics(b.toUpperCase())));
  print(data);
           
}

final defaultDiacriticsRemovalap = [
    {'base':'A', 'letters':'\u0041\u24B6\uFF21\u00C0\u00C1\u00C2\u1EA6\u1EA4\u1EAA\u1EA8\u00C3\u0100\u0102\u1EB0\u1EAE\u1EB4\u1EB2\u0226\u01E0\u00C4\u01DE\u1EA2\u00C5\u01FA\u01CD\u0200\u0202\u1EA0\u1EAC\u1EB6\u1E00\u0104\u023A\u2C6F'},
    {'base':'AA','letters':'\uA732'},
    {'base':'AE','letters':'\u00C6\u01FC\u01E2'},
    {'base':'AO','letters':'\uA734'},
    {'base':'AU','letters':'\uA736'},
    {'base':'AV','letters':'\uA738\uA73A'},
    {'base':'AY','letters':'\uA73C'},
    {'base':'B', 'letters':'\u0042\u24B7\uFF22\u1E02\u1E04\u1E06\u0243\u0182\u0181'},
    {'base':'C', 'letters':'\u0043\u24B8\uFF23\u0106\u0108\u010A\u010C\u00C7\u1E08\u0187\u023B\uA73E'},
    {'base':'D', 'letters':'\u0044\u24B9\uFF24\u1E0A\u010E\u1E0C\u1E10\u1E12\u1E0E\u0110\u018B\u018A\u0189\uA779'},
    {'base':'DZ','letters':'\u01F1\u01C4'},
    {'base':'Dz','letters':'\u01F2\u01C5'},
    {'base':'E', 'letters':'\u0045\u24BA\uFF25\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u1EC0\u1EBE\u1EC4\u1EC2\u1EBC\u0112\u1E14\u1E16\u0114\u0116\u00CB\u1EBA\u011A\u0204\u0206\u1EB8\u1EC6\u0228\u1E1C\u0118\u1E18\u1E1A\u0190\u018E'},
    {'base':'F', 'letters':'\u0046\u24BB\uFF26\u1E1E\u0191\uA77B'},
    {'base':'G', 'letters':'\u0047\u24BC\uFF27\u01F4\u011C\u1E20\u011E\u0120\u01E6\u0122\u01E4\u0193\uA7A0\uA77D\uA77E'},
    {'base':'H', 'letters':'\u0048\u24BD\uFF28\u0124\u1E22\u1E26\u021E\u1E24\u1E28\u1E2A\u0126\u2C67\u2C75\uA78D'},
    {'base':'I', 'letters':'\u0049\u24BE\uFF29\u00CC\u00CD\u00CE\u0128\u012A\u012C\u0130\u00CF\u1E2E\u1EC8\u01CF\u0208\u020A\u1ECA\u012E\u1E2C\u0197'},
    {'base':'J', 'letters':'\u004A\u24BF\uFF2A\u0134\u0248'},
    {'base':'K', 'letters':'\u004B\u24C0\uFF2B\u1E30\u01E8\u1E32\u0136\u1E34\u0198\u2C69\uA740\uA742\uA744\uA7A2'},
    {'base':'L', 'letters':'\u004C\u24C1\uFF2C\u013F\u0139\u013D\u1E36\u1E38\u013B\u1E3C\u1E3A\u0141\u023D\u2C62\u2C60\uA748\uA746\uA780'},
    {'base':'LJ','letters':'\u01C7'},
    {'base':'Lj','letters':'\u01C8'},
    {'base':'M', 'letters':'\u004D\u24C2\uFF2D\u1E3E\u1E40\u1E42\u2C6E\u019C'},
    {'base':'N', 'letters':'\u004E\u24C3\uFF2E\u01F8\u0143\u00D1\u1E44\u0147\u1E46\u0145\u1E4A\u1E48\u0220\u019D\uA790\uA7A4'},
    {'base':'NJ','letters':'\u01CA'},
    {'base':'Nj','letters':'\u01CB'},
    {'base':'O', 'letters':'\u004F\u24C4\uFF2F\u00D2\u00D3\u00D4\u1ED2\u1ED0\u1ED6\u1ED4\u00D5\u1E4C\u022C\u1E4E\u014C\u1E50\u1E52\u014E\u022E\u0230\u00D6\u022A\u1ECE\u0150\u01D1\u020C\u020E\u01A0\u1EDC\u1EDA\u1EE0\u1EDE\u1EE2\u1ECC\u1ED8\u01EA\u01EC\u00D8\u01FE\u0186\u019F\uA74A\uA74C'},
    {'base':'OI','letters':'\u01A2'},
    {'base':'OO','letters':'\uA74E'},
    {'base':'OU','letters':'\u0222'},
    {'base':'OE','letters':'\u008C\u0152'},
    {'base':'oe','letters':'\u009C\u0153'},
    {'base':'P', 'letters':'\u0050\u24C5\uFF30\u1E54\u1E56\u01A4\u2C63\uA750\uA752\uA754'},
    {'base':'Q', 'letters':'\u0051\u24C6\uFF31\uA756\uA758\u024A'},
    {'base':'R', 'letters':'\u0052\u24C7\uFF32\u0154\u1E58\u0158\u0210\u0212\u1E5A\u1E5C\u0156\u1E5E\u024C\u2C64\uA75A\uA7A6\uA782'},
    {'base':'S', 'letters':'\u0053\u24C8\uFF33\u1E9E\u015A\u1E64\u015C\u1E60\u0160\u1E66\u1E62\u1E68\u0218\u015E\u2C7E\uA7A8\uA784'},
    {'base':'T', 'letters':'\u0054\u24C9\uFF34\u1E6A\u0164\u1E6C\u021A\u0162\u1E70\u1E6E\u0166\u01AC\u01AE\u023E\uA786'},
    {'base':'TZ','letters':'\uA728'},
    {'base':'U', 'letters':'\u0055\u24CA\uFF35\u00D9\u00DA\u00DB\u0168\u1E78\u016A\u1E7A\u016C\u00DC\u01DB\u01D7\u01D5\u01D9\u1EE6\u016E\u0170\u01D3\u0214\u0216\u01AF\u1EEA\u1EE8\u1EEE\u1EEC\u1EF0\u1EE4\u1E72\u0172\u1E76\u1E74\u0244'},
    {'base':'V', 'letters':'\u0056\u24CB\uFF36\u1E7C\u1E7E\u01B2\uA75E\u0245'},
    {'base':'VY','letters':'\uA760'},
    {'base':'W', 'letters':'\u0057\u24CC\uFF37\u1E80\u1E82\u0174\u1E86\u1E84\u1E88\u2C72'},
    {'base':'X', 'letters':'\u0058\u24CD\uFF38\u1E8A\u1E8C'},
    {'base':'Y', 'letters':'\u0059\u24CE\uFF39\u1EF2\u00DD\u0176\u1EF8\u0232\u1E8E\u0178\u1EF6\u1EF4\u01B3\u024E\u1EFE'},
    {'base':'Z', 'letters':'\u005A\u24CF\uFF3A\u0179\u1E90\u017B\u017D\u1E92\u1E94\u01B5\u0224\u2C7F\u2C6B\uA762'},
    {'base':'a', 'letters':'\u0061\u24D0\uFF41\u1E9A\u00E0\u00E1\u00E2\u1EA7\u1EA5\u1EAB\u1EA9\u00E3\u0101\u0103\u1EB1\u1EAF\u1EB5\u1EB3\u0227\u01E1\u00E4\u01DF\u1EA3\u00E5\u01FB\u01CE\u0201\u0203\u1EA1\u1EAD\u1EB7\u1E01\u0105\u2C65\u0250'},
    {'base':'aa','letters':'\uA733'},
    {'base':'ae','letters':'\u00E6\u01FD\u01E3'},
    {'base':'ao','letters':'\uA735'},
    {'base':'au','letters':'\uA737'},
    {'base':'av','letters':'\uA739\uA73B'},
    {'base':'ay','letters':'\uA73D'},
    {'base':'b', 'letters':'\u0062\u24D1\uFF42\u1E03\u1E05\u1E07\u0180\u0183\u0253'},
    {'base':'c', 'letters':'\u0063\u24D2\uFF43\u0107\u0109\u010B\u010D\u00E7\u1E09\u0188\u023C\uA73F\u2184'},
    {'base':'d', 'letters':'\u0064\u24D3\uFF44\u1E0B\u010F\u1E0D\u1E11\u1E13\u1E0F\u0111\u018C\u0256\u0257\uA77A'},
    {'base':'dz','letters':'\u01F3\u01C6'},
    {'base':'e', 'letters':'\u0065\u24D4\uFF45\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u1EC1\u1EBF\u1EC5\u1EC3\u1EBD\u0113\u1E15\u1E17\u0115\u0117\u00EB\u1EBB\u011B\u0205\u0207\u1EB9\u1EC7\u0229\u1E1D\u0119\u1E19\u1E1B\u0247\u025B\u01DD'},
    {'base':'f', 'letters':'\u0066\u24D5\uFF46\u1E1F\u0192\uA77C'},
    {'base':'g', 'letters':'\u0067\u24D6\uFF47\u01F5\u011D\u1E21\u011F\u0121\u01E7\u0123\u01E5\u0260\uA7A1\u1D79\uA77F'},
    {'base':'h', 'letters':'\u0068\u24D7\uFF48\u0125\u1E23\u1E27\u021F\u1E25\u1E29\u1E2B\u1E96\u0127\u2C68\u2C76\u0265'},
    {'base':'hv','letters':'\u0195'},
    {'base':'i', 'letters':'\u0069\u24D8\uFF49\u00EC\u00ED\u00EE\u0129\u012B\u012D\u00EF\u1E2F\u1EC9\u01D0\u0209\u020B\u1ECB\u012F\u1E2D\u0268\u0131'},
    {'base':'j', 'letters':'\u006A\u24D9\uFF4A\u0135\u01F0\u0249'},
    {'base':'k', 'letters':'\u006B\u24DA\uFF4B\u1E31\u01E9\u1E33\u0137\u1E35\u0199\u2C6A\uA741\uA743\uA745\uA7A3'},
    {'base':'l', 'letters':'\u006C\u24DB\uFF4C\u0140\u013A\u013E\u1E37\u1E39\u013C\u1E3D\u1E3B\u017F\u0142\u019A\u026B\u2C61\uA749\uA781\uA747'},
    {'base':'lj','letters':'\u01C9'},
    {'base':'m', 'letters':'\u006D\u24DC\uFF4D\u1E3F\u1E41\u1E43\u0271\u026F'},
    {'base':'n', 'letters':'\u006E\u24DD\uFF4E\u01F9\u0144\u00F1\u1E45\u0148\u1E47\u0146\u1E4B\u1E49\u019E\u0272\u0149\uA791\uA7A5'},
    {'base':'nj','letters':'\u01CC'},
    {'base':'o', 'letters':'\u006F\u24DE\uFF4F\u00F2\u00F3\u00F4\u1ED3\u1ED1\u1ED7\u1ED5\u00F5\u1E4D\u022D\u1E4F\u014D\u1E51\u1E53\u014F\u022F\u0231\u00F6\u022B\u1ECF\u0151\u01D2\u020D\u020F\u01A1\u1EDD\u1EDB\u1EE1\u1EDF\u1EE3\u1ECD\u1ED9\u01EB\u01ED\u00F8\u01FF\u0254\uA74B\uA74D\u0275'},
    {'base':'oi','letters':'\u01A3'},
    {'base':'ou','letters':'\u0223'},
    {'base':'oo','letters':'\uA74F'},
    {'base':'p','letters':'\u0070\u24DF\uFF50\u1E55\u1E57\u01A5\u1D7D\uA751\uA753\uA755'},
    {'base':'q','letters':'\u0071\u24E0\uFF51\u024B\uA757\uA759'},
    {'base':'r','letters':'\u0072\u24E1\uFF52\u0155\u1E59\u0159\u0211\u0213\u1E5B\u1E5D\u0157\u1E5F\u024D\u027D\uA75B\uA7A7\uA783'},
    {'base':'s','letters':'\u0073\u24E2\uFF53\u00DF\u015B\u1E65\u015D\u1E61\u0161\u1E67\u1E63\u1E69\u0219\u015F\u023F\uA7A9\uA785\u1E9B'},
    {'base':'t','letters':'\u0074\u24E3\uFF54\u1E6B\u1E97\u0165\u1E6D\u021B\u0163\u1E71\u1E6F\u0167\u01AD\u0288\u2C66\uA787'},
    {'base':'tz','letters':'\uA729'},
    {'base':'u','letters': '\u0075\u24E4\uFF55\u00F9\u00FA\u00FB\u0169\u1E79\u016B\u1E7B\u016D\u00FC\u01DC\u01D8\u01D6\u01DA\u1EE7\u016F\u0171\u01D4\u0215\u0217\u01B0\u1EEB\u1EE9\u1EEF\u1EED\u1EF1\u1EE5\u1E73\u0173\u1E77\u1E75\u0289'},
    {'base':'v','letters':'\u0076\u24E5\uFF56\u1E7D\u1E7F\u028B\uA75F\u028C'},
    {'base':'vy','letters':'\uA761'},
    {'base':'w','letters':'\u0077\u24E6\uFF57\u1E81\u1E83\u0175\u1E87\u1E85\u1E98\u1E89\u2C73'},
    {'base':'x','letters':'\u0078\u24E7\uFF58\u1E8B\u1E8D'},
    {'base':'y','letters':'\u0079\u24E8\uFF59\u1EF3\u00FD\u0177\u1EF9\u0233\u1E8F\u00FF\u1EF7\u1E99\u1EF5\u01B4\u024F\u1EFF'},
    {'base':'z','letters':'\u007A\u24E9\uFF5A\u017A\u1E91\u017C\u017E\u1E93\u1E95\u01B6\u0225\u0240\u2C6C\uA763'}
];

final diacriticsMap = {};

final diacriticsRegExp = new RegExp('[^\u0000-\u007E]', multiLine: true);

String removeDiacritics(String str) {
  if(diacriticsMap.isEmpty) {
    for (var i=0; i < defaultDiacriticsRemovalap.length; i++){
      var letters = defaultDiacriticsRemovalap[i]['letters'];
      for (var j=0; j < (letters.length) ; j++){
          diacriticsMap[letters[j]] = defaultDiacriticsRemovalap[i]['base'];
      }
    }
  }
    // "what?" version ... http://jsperf.com/diacritics/12
  return str.replaceAllMapped(diacriticsRegExp, (a){
    return diacriticsMap[a.group(0)] != null ? diacriticsMap[a.group(0)] : a.group(0);
  });
}
```